# Symfony repository: get supervised items

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a Item Entity with an owner attribute so that I can show only items to the logged in user. The user entity has an supervisor attribute, which is an other user. In twig I can compare item.owner.supervisor.id to the logged in user. But now I want to create an repository function to show all owned and supervised items.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
  ->select('i')
  ->where('i.owner = :user_id')      
  ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This is my current function that works with owned items. If I use

```
->where('i.owner.supervisor = :user_id')
```

I get an error, because supervisor is not an property of item. I don´t actually see a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I created a other query where I get all users where i am a supervisor.

```
$owner = $this->createQueryBuilder('us')
  ->select('u.id')
  ->from('MyBundle:User', 'u')
  ->where('u.supervidor = :user_id')
  ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());
$ownerResult = $owner->getQuery()->getResult();

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
  ->select('i')
  ->where('i.owner = :user_id')
  ->orWhere('i.owner IN (:subs)')
  ->setParameter('subs', $ownerResult)
  ->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```